# create array instead of repeating a function

Tags: php, mysql

```
function givemebann($pos) {
    global $db;
    $st = $db->prepare("select * from banners where home = '" . $pos . "' limit 1");
    $st->execute();
    return $st->fetch();
}

<div class='bigwrap' id='bigwrap'>
<?php
$row = givemebann('big-top');
$x = $row['src'];
?>
<img class='bigbann' src='../banners/<?php echo $x; ?>' alt='img'>
</div>
```

This all works but I have `50` such places on a single page.
`givemebann('left-a');`
`givemebann('right-b');`
... etc

So, I need to reduce this communication between php and mysql server and I suppose the solution is to create an array of values and then get them inside html from that array.

I need any help to create such array?

Comment: All `$pos` value needs to be iterated in a loop and put in a single array. Either way different results will be fetched from the database for each call.

Comment: why don't you get all positions at once in a single query and then iterate the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be wise if you select only the column(s) that you really need in your SQL query rather than all the existing columns:

```
// declare all the banners that you will need on this page
$banner_list = Array('"left-a"', '"right-b"', '"big-top"', '"small-bottom"');

// get all the required banners
$st = $db->prepare("select home, src from banners where home IN (" . implode(",",$banner_list) . ") GROUP BY home");
$st->execute();
$result = $st->fetchAll();
foreach($result as &$row) $banners[$row['home']] = $row;

<div class='bigwrap' id='bigwrap'>
<?php
$row = $banners['big-top'];
$x = $row['src'];
?>
<img class='bigbann' src='../banners/<?php echo $x; ?>' alt='img'>
</div>
```